# Digits should know their place

Tags: beginner, c, programming-challenge

#### Challenge

Swap the numbers surrounding the words in sentences.

#### Specifications

1. The first argument is a path to a file.
2. The file contains multiple lines.
3. Each line is a test case represented by a sentence.
4. Each sentence begins and ends with a number.
5. Print out the sentence obtained by swapping the numbers surrounding each word.

#### Constraints

1. The suffix and the prefix of each word may be equal.
2. Sentences are from 1 to 17 words long.
3. The number of test cases is 40.
4. All characters are ASCII.
5. The numbers are single digit positive intgers 0-9.

**Sample Input**

> 4Always0 5look8 4on9 7the2 4bright8 9side7 3of8 5life5
> 5Nobody5 7expects3 5the4 6Spanish4 9inquisition0

**Sample Output**

> 0Always4 8look5 9on4 2the7 8bright4 7side9 8of3 5life5
> 5Nobody5 3expects7 4the5 4Spanish6 0inquisition9

[Source](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/196/)

#### My solution

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LINE_BUFFER 256

int fileExists(char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file != NULL) {
        fclose(file);
    }
    return file != NULL;
}

void swapNumbers(char line[LINE_BUFFER]) {
    int temp = 0;
    int position = 0;
    int swapped = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < LINE_BUFFER; i++) {
        if (isdigit(line[i])) {
            if (!swapped) {
                position = i;
                temp = line[i];
                swapped = 1;
            } else {
                line[position] = line[i];
                line[i] = temp;
                swapped = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *args[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        puts("File path not provided.");
        return 1;
    }

    if (argc > 2) {
        puts("Excessive arguments, only the first will be considered.");
    }

    if (!fileExists(args[1])) {
        puts("Could not access file / file not found.");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(args[1], "r");
    char line[LINE_BUFFER];

    while (fgets(line, LINE_BUFFER, file)) {
        swapNumbers(line);
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm `fclose(file);  } return file != NULL;` uses the pointer value `file` after the `fclose()`.  I suspect this is generally OK, but smells of potential UB: using a pointer after it is no longer valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
>     if (!fileExists(args[1])) {
>         puts("Could not access file / file not found.");
>         return 1;
>     }
>
>     FILE *file = fopen(args[1], "r");
> ```

This seems more complicated than necessary.

```
    FILE *file = fopen(args[1], "r");
    if (NULL == file) {
        puts("Could not access file / file not found.");
        return 1;
    }
```

This has the exact same effect as `fileExists` but it leaves you with an open file handle.  The other method tested that it could open a file and then assumed that the second open worked.  So it's actually slightly less safe, as well as more code.

You might argue that it would be extremely rare for the first open to succeed and the second one to fail.  I agree with you.  But rare is not never.  Thus, "slightly" less safe.

> ```
>     int temp = 0;
>     int position = 0;
>     int swapped = 0;
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < LINE_BUFFER; i++) {
>         if (isdigit(line[i])) {
>             if (!swapped) {
>                 position = i;
>                 temp = line[i];
>                 swapped = 1;
>             } else {
>                 line[position] = line[i];
>                 line[i] = temp;
>                 swapped = 0;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

I don't like using negative test conditions.  I'd normally fix this by switching the `if` and `else` blocks.  In this case though, the current order makes more sense.

My second thought was that the name was wrong.  So I was going to change the name to `needs_swapped` or similar.  But then I realized that if I changed the name, the current form would be correct.  The name `swapped` is actually backwards.  When `swapped` is true, then you haven't swapped but need to do so.  So my third thought was to simply swap the meaning.

```
    int temp = 0;
    int position = 0;
    int swapped = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < LINE_BUFFER; i++) {
        if (isdigit(line[i])) {
            if (swapped) {
                position = i;
                temp = line[i];
                swapped = 0;
            } else {
                line[position] = line[i];
                line[i] = temp;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I have the `else` as the negative of the condition, which I like.  And we've also made it so that when `swapped` is 1 (true in C parlance), we've just swapped.  When `swapped` is 0 (false in C), we're ready to swap.

But I actually think that there is a more idiomatic way to do this in C.  You are saving an index (`position`), a value (`temp`), and a Boolean (`swapped`).  But you actually only need to save the location.  Consider

```
    char *location = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < LINE_BUFFER; i++) {
        if (isdigit(line[i])) {
            if (NULL == location) {
                location = &line[i];
            } else {
                int temp = *location;
                *location = line[i];
                line[i] = temp;
                location = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
```

or less explicitly (and slightly out of order)

```
    char *location = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < LINE_BUFFER; i++) {
        if (isdigit(line[i])) {
            if (location) {
                int temp = *location;
                *location = line[i];
                line[i] = temp;
                location = NULL;
            } else {
                location = line + i;
            }
        }
    }
```

Either version reduces three variables at function scope down to one at function scope and one at the most local block scope.

It's up to you which version you find more readable.  I also switched between `line + i` and `&line[i]`.  They do the same thing, so it's pretty much a readability difference.

And I like this better, as rather than using a Boolean to track whether or not we need to swap, we track based on whether we know where to swap.  Less parallel logic increases robustness.

Twice now I've used the notation `NULL == variable` (where `variable` is any declared variable like `location` or `file`).  The reason for this is that in C, `if (variable = NULL) {` is valid and will compile and run.  It creates unreachable code, as `NULL` will always be false.  So modern compilers often warn on this.  But it's valid grammatically.  If you instead always write `if (VALUE == variable) {` (where `VALUE` is any constant like `NULL` or `3`), then a typo leads to `if (VALUE = variable) {` which is not valid and won't compile.

Like I said, most modern compilers will warn on this.  So it's not as important as it once was.  But if you start editing C code, you are likely to see this idiom used.  This is why.

Answer (score 3):

Bug: potentially accessing `line[i]` pass the null character.  Instead, stop on the null character.

```
// for (int i = 0; i < LINE_BUFFER; i++) {
for (int i = 0; i < line[i]; i++) {
  if (isdigit(line[i])) {
```

`#define LINE_BUFFER 256` is not necessarily sufficient as there is no limit on "word" length.  To handle requirements, a new approach is needed.

Pedantic: Using `isdigit()` with negative values, aside from `EOF`, is UB.  Not a concern here given "All characters are ASCII.".

```
// if (isdigit(line[i])) {
if (isdigit((unsigned char) line[i])) {
```